# Beginning and End of the month dates based upon a dynamic value

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, etl

Using SSIS 2013, I have a table which has an invoice date stored as an integer in the format of `YYYYMMDD` and I need to determine the beginning of the month date and the end of the month date based upon the invoice date.  Both the beginning and end dates will also be stored as integers.

For example my invoice date is: `20170512`
and I want to return:`20170501` (BeginDate)
and 20170531 (`EndingDate`)

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Two Derived COlumns with the following expressions"

*These Expression will return 2 Columns of type `DT_DATE`*

**First Day:**

```
(DT_DATE)(LEFT([InvoiceDate],4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([InvoiceDate],5,2) + "-01")
```

**Last Day:**

```
DATEADD("d",-1,DATEADD("m",1,(DT_DATE)(LEFT([InvoiceDate],4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([InvoiceDate],5,2) + "-01")))
```

*If you need to return 2 columns with the same format `YYYYMMDD`*

**First Day:**

```
LEFT([InvoiceDate],4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([InvoiceDate],5,2) + "-01"
```

**Last Day:**

```
LEFT([InvoiceDate],4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([InvoiceDate],5,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("d",-1,DATEADD("m",1,(DT_DATE)(LEFT([InvoiceDate],4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([InvoiceDate],5,2) + "-01")))),2)
```

Comment: Thanks Hadi, I modified your answers slightly to first move the invoice date to a string then removed the dashes.   Then I moved that output to a integer column and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @gbdeveloper if this answer solved your issue you have to accept it, also if you find it helpful feel free to upvote :)

Comment: @gbdeveloper it is good to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more on accepting and upvoting answers